# How can I test whether $\sum (n+\cos(n))/(n^3*\log(n^2+4))$ is convergent or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to find out whether the series 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n + \cos n}{n^3 \log (n^2+4)}
$$

is convergent or not.

I tried the ratio test first, but it seems does work because there will be $\cos(n)$ and $\cos(n+1)$ in numerator and denominator. I can't really find a way to compare those two terms. Then I tried to find the limit of when n goes to infinity but the $\cos(n)$ really confused me. $\cos$ of infinity is a undefined value so I cant really continue on this question. Am I using the right method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\left|\frac{n+\cos n}{n^3\log(n^2+4)}\right|\leqslant\frac{n+1}{n^3}=\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^3}\leqslant\frac2{n^2},$$your series converges absolutely.

Comment: Sorry im still a bit confused, this equation does make sense but how am i gonna prove this? Because both numerator and denominator are smaller when comparing to the original equation.

Comment: @LikaiLiu It's the direct comparison test.

Comment: @AndrewLi I do understand its the comparison test. But aren't we supposed to change only one part of a fraction in order to use the comparison test?  In this case its obvious because log of infinity would be a really large number, which has much stronger influence comparing to the cos(n) in numerator. Does this method applies to other similar questions?

Comment: @LikaiLiu I've edited my answer. What I used was that $|n+\cos n|\leqslant n+1$ and that $|n^3\log(n^2+4)|\geqslant n^3$.

Comment: @LikaiLiu Since $n^3\log(\dots)$ will increase faster than $n^3$, the denominator will be larger, thus, smaller fraction overall.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I got it, replacing cos(n) with largest possible value 1 is such an brilliant idea. Thanks you so much

Comment: @LikaiLiu If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.